# How to let C# windows application start with a default combo box item selected?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, default

I am using c#,

I have a window form containing a combo-box.
How to let the application start with a default item selected in that combo-box ?

Comment: you can set selectedindex property for that OnLoad of you form..

Comment: It accept only -1 , but when i try other values like 1 it give me error

Comment: that means your combobox has no items,check combobox count

Comment: Did you insert values in your combobox? If not, you will get an out of range exception.

Comment: InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.

Comment: show us ur code,if still not done.

Comment: wc,debug more it will help you out.

Comment: @Alzayed if one of the answers below helped you solve your problem, please mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if( comboBox1.Items.Count>0)          
        {
             comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
      else
        {   
             comboBox1.Text="No Items";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of your form set the `Selectedindex` property of your comboBox to your desired item.

```
public Form1()
{    
  InitializeComponent();
  comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0; //or whatever item you want here
}
```

You could also use the load event of your form and even of your combobox:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use in your constructor something like:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

or

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SomeClass someItem;
    comboBox.SelectedItem = someItem;
}
```

or

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    comboBox.SelectedText = "someText";
    // or 
    // comboBox.Text = "someText";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Form Load

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Comcombobox1.SelectedIndex=0;

    }
```

set selected index what ever you want